# Right way to handle this inotify race?

Tags: linux, inotify

I want to maintain a cache that mirrors a particular directory, so I add a watch whose events are monitored by thread A and then tell thread B to scan that directory and put the filenames into my cache. I have separate threads because I want the application to still be responsive to incoming inotify events during the scan. Otherwise, I could lose events because I wasn't reading them and the inotify queue filled up during the scan.

It is entirely possible that a delete or move_from event for a file will be processed before it was added to my cache by the directory scan. In that case a naive implementation would end up having a cache entry referring to a file that doesn't exist. What's the right way deal with this particular race condition?

Comment: Things are actually even worse than you think: a directory can change *during* a readdir call, leading to missing or duplicate file entries in results. But that does not matter in practice — just treat results of `File#list` as list of files, that *might* be there and adequately handle any `FileNotFoundException`s. More importantly — from your question it sounds like you are trying to modify a cache from both threads. Don't do that. Let your inotify loop thread do the reading from inotify descriptor; when an even appears, send notification to reader thread, so it modifies the cache for you.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're saying here, why would the inotify reader thread send something to a temporary directory reader thread? Even if only one thread actually manages the cache, you still have an ordering problem. If whatever thread manages the cache receives a delete or move_from event (which deletes a non-existent cache entry) followed by an add to cache event (from the temporary readdir thread) that add to cache event creates a cache entry referring to a file that's already been deleted. What's the solution, create a cache entry on delete and delete it on add? Makes for wonky logic.

Comment: "If whatever thread manages the cache receives a delete or move_from event (which deletes a non-existent cache entry) followed by an add to cache event (from the temporary readdir thread)" ­— why are you suddenly introducing a third thread? Your question described a single thread reading from descriptor and another thread doing readdir… There is no reason  to introduce more threads into equation. Even second thread is mostly unnecessary. "I'm not sure… why would the inotify reader thread send something" — read up about message queues before trying to do more multi-threaded programming

Comment: I didn’t add a third thread. There’s an inotify thread and a readdir thread. I imagined the latter to be temporary, sending “found a file” events to the other, then exiting. There is a race to resolve regardless of who sends to whom or what communication mechanism is used. If I were certain the inotify queue couldn’t fill up and start dropping events while I’m processing the directory with readdir I wouldn’t bother with a second thread.

Comment: Ah, I see. Sending multiple "found a file" events would have been rather expensive, so I haven't thought of such scenario. Rather, I imagined, that your readdir thread just straight up clears the cache for the specific directory and populates it anew from the readdir() results (and inotify thread cancels scheduled readdir() if new event arrives during it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I'd have done it is to keep two permanent threads: a single *utility thread* and single *inotify thread* for non-stop reading from inotify file descriptor. These threads communicate via blocking queue.

When *inotify thread* detects an event, that can be one of two event types:

1. An event, indicating, that entire cache for the observed directory must be destroyed and re-created: queue overflow or unmount.
2. An event, that can be handled by changing a single entry in cache (most other inotify events)

Upon detection, the event is immediately queued to *utility thread*.

When *utility thread* receives event of 1st type, it recreaters entire cache from scratch by reading full directory contents into cache. The same happens, when there is no cache yet, and the event of 2nd type arrives. In other cases full readdir() is avoided, and the cache is simply modified according to event.

---

The race condition, described in your question, may happen only if multiple threads are allowed to modify the cache. The described approach handles it by assuming, that the only thread allowed to modify a cache is *utility thread*.

If you want to allow other threads to modify the cache (for example, because you don't know if inotify is supported by filesystem), you can use a simpler and more robust approach: do not track individual directory modification events and have *utility thread* perform full readdir() on every arriving event. In the worst case there will be too much readdirs, but reading directory contents by itself is so cheap, I wouldn't care about that.

If reading full directory contents is *not* cheap (for example, because it may be very, very big), then you shouldn't store all of it in memory to begin with. Such scenario would better work with small partial cache, that can be quickly refreshed by using `telldir`, `seek` and `fstat` to track small number of files, currently visible to user.